# Use checkbox value to determine content on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im having some issues with an ASP.NET project of mine.

I have a page that loads a number of records from a Time and Attendance system. Some of these lines are marked as cancelled.

Now what im trying to achieve is the following:

If my checkbox on the top of the page is checked - i want the code that loads lines into my view to skip the lines that are marked as cancelled.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ShowCancelled" name="ShowCancelled" id="ShowCancelled" onchange="document.forms[0].submit();" /><label for="ShowCancelled">Vis annullerede linier?</label>
```

The checkbox submits my form that contains the checkbox upon change.

The idea is to modify my Foreach loop to skip files from the view that are cancelled.

```
<% if (Model.postedTRecs != null)
               {
                   foreach (var line in Model.postedTRecs)
                   {
                       // Show only students
                       if ((line.isStudent))
                       {
                            //Logic to display line.
                       }
                   }
               }
```

I was kind of hoping i could somehow check the value of my checkbox in the foreach loop and make sure that line.Cancelled was set to false.

However i am a little confused about how i reach for the checked value in the foreach loop and how i make sure the checkbox isnt reset when i submit the page.

any input would be greatly appreciated.

A

Comment: It looks like you're submitting the form onchange. That would imply the checkbox value is included in the POST data. I would think you could check for its value when querying for the Model data, and filter it appropriately?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how i would go about doing that?

Comment: If you can check the POST contents to see if that checkbox value is checked, you could potentially use that in the code that populates the model, and then filter the result set using Linq or some other method. That way you dont have to use the View and modify the loop at all.

Comment: Ahh like that. Im afraid i cant use that approach since there is other critical logic manipulating the lines in the view. yes its dirty i know. :( Thanks though